# What do you call someone who acts like they're doing you a favor?

Tags: expressions

Say you go in for a job interview and you're nervous and the person interviewing you makes it seem like they're doing you a favor or like an obligation they must gratefully oblige, what would that person be called? I know there's a term for it but I can't think of it.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361561/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-does-favors-for-others-because-they-want-somethi

Comment: 'Doing you a favour' because you are barely worth their time, or because the job is an awesome opportunity and anyone would be lucky to have it?

Comment: Also related (and off-topic): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541433/verb-to-describe-a-way-of-talking-to-people-as-if-they-owed-you-something. Welcome to EL&U, by the way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb to describe a way of talking to people as if they owed you something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541433/verb-to-describe-a-way-of-talking-to-people-as-if-they-owed-you-something)

Comment: To the extent that interviewers put time aside for the interview, you might consider that they are doing you a sort of favor...and treat them accordingly. If you begrudge their 'graciousness', don't be surprised if it gets worse. This is the value of the [white lie](https://guerillaparentingbyyosefbaskin.blogspot.com/2011/02/blog-post_20.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could say that they are patronizing you.

> **Patronize (verb):** to treat in a condescending manner, often in showing interest or kindness that is insincere: felt she was being patronized by her supervisor.

[American Heritage dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=patronize)